# Guarding against accidental change to copy/view semantics during refactoring

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `class Board` that represents a board with some pieces on it. The pieces are represented by `namedtuple`, and are stored in an attribute `_pieces`, which is just a dictionary (its keys are positions on the board, its values are pieces).

`Board` has a method `get_rectangle`, which should return a *copy* of positions and pieces in the specified rectangle on the board. It does so simply by creating and returning a new dictionary with the positions filtered appropriately.

Much later, during refactoring, pieces change from `namedtuple` to `class` and become mutable. This causes a difficult bug: the dictionary returned from `get_rectangle` is no longer a copy (it shares the pieces objects with the board).

Of course, after this bug is found, it's very easy to fix. But what techniques are available to avoid this problem? Was there any obvious problem with the original design?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you make a copy of the dictionary, you are copying the references to the objects as opposed to the objects themselves. Because the tuples are immutable, this would have avoided any problems of modifying the original. Have you looked at using [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) in order to avoid this problem?

Comment: Yes, of course `deepcopy` would solve it. But early on, when the objects were immutable, `deepcopy` would have looked unnecessarily complex. We don't usually use `deepcopy` to create a copy of a list with integers for example...